# How to get the array after nth iteration in bubble sort?

Tags: javascript, arrays, printing, iteration, bubble-sort

Here is the bubble sort algorithm in javascript(removed `swap` function for brevity)

```
const bubbleSort = (arr, iter) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - i - 1; j++) {
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        swap(arr, j, j + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
};
```

The second argument `iter` represents iteration. I want this method to return the array after `iter` number of iterations. For example, consider this array

`array = [3, 5, 8, 4, 1, 9, -2]`

```
After iteration 1: array = [3, 5, 4, 1, 8, -2, 9]  
After iteration 2: array = [3, 4, 1, 5, -2, 8, 9]  
.  
.  
After iteration 5: array = [1, -2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]  
After iteration 6: array = [-2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]
```

So essentially if I call `bubblesort(array, 5)`, it should return [1, -2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]

Comment: if i get it right, on `i == iter` `break` the loop?

Comment: Your code is not correct.

Comment: @PM77-1 Um, could you be more specific? The bubble sort code is the classical one that I pulled from wiki.

Comment: Your internal loop is not dependent on `i`.

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `for` loop and `forEach` loop inside to swap elements.

```js
let array = [3, 5, 8, 4, 1, 9, -2]

function bubblesort(arr, n) {
  for (let x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    arr.forEach((e, i) => {
      if (arr[i + 1] < e) {
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1]
        arr[i + 1] = e
      }
    })
  }
  return arr
}

console.log(bubblesort(array, 5))
```

Comment: That's pretty much exactly my answer, and I got 2 downvotes.

Comment: @Nenad This function is just printing to console. I want the function to return that arr after nth iteration. I am planning to use that in another function of mine later.

Comment: @theprogrammer094 It does return the array after n iterations, console.log is just for the demo.

Comment: Indeed you are right. My bad, did not see the outer for loop. I think this works. Thanks.

Comment: @theprogrammer094 Note that this modifies and returns the original array, if you want to create new array you could just create copy with slice inside function

Comment: Yes, it does indeed modify, which is what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: Hey just as a side question, I just realized that this gives us the iteration after the highest element ends up going to the right. But if we wanted to get each iteration before that happens, what changes do we need to make to your code to get that? Like if each bubbling is considered as a step/iteration, then what changes to make? Hope I made sense.

Comment: @theprogrammer094 You could use generator in that case https://jsfiddle.net/sfu9kt5h/32/

Answer (score -2):

If you want the Nth iteration, just run the whole thing N times, then return the result?

```
var array = [3, 5, 8, 4, 1, 9, -2]

const bubbleSort = (arr, iter) => {
  for (var n = 0; n < iter; n++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
          swap(arr, j - 1, j);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
};

bubbleSort(array,5)
```

Comment: the outer for you added is adding extra load and helping with nothing. The array will be sorted before the value of n becomes even 1

Comment: What do you mean? I don't get it. Won't `bubbleSort(array,5)` sort the array 5 times then return the result?

Comment: yes, exactly! it will (try to) sort it 4 more times than needed which is something extra and will not change the array at all. What is asked was to break the loops when N iterations (not complete sortings) are done

Comment: I still don't get it. What's the difference between one iteration and one "complete sorting"? What do you mean "complete sorting"? Is there a partial sorting here?

Comment: yes, partial sorting is what the user asks here. Several iterations are needed (if the array is not already sorted) in order to achieve a complete sort

Comment: Aaaah, I get it now. Thanks for the explanation. My answer is indeed wrong.